# dojox.grid.DataGrid hide/disable the header of the grid

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

I need a option to hide the header from a dojox.grid.DataGrid grid.
Didn't find anything.
I'm grateful for any info!

Answer (score 4):

I use in dojo 1.6 (and probably works since dojo 1.3)

```
#myGrid .dojoxGridHeader  { display:none; }
```

Comment: thank you, this should be mentioned in the dojo documentation :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS:

.dojoxGrid-header { display:none; }

This solution is taken from:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#hiding-the-headers-of-a-grid

Answer (score 0):

u can connect at the postrender of the data grid. then find the headerGrid element created
then put style display to none.

```
 //workaround the grid calls postrender after
                            //the component is at the dom.
                            //so then i can change the style to reset the header to invisible
                            dojo.connect(grid,"postrender",function(){
                                  var headerGrid =this.domNode.firstElementChild;
                                    headerGrid.style.display="none";
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to using the [new and improved dgrid](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki) instead of datagrid, it is a lot better!

The setting for hiding headers is the attribute 'showHeader' which is a boolean value.

Check out this [dgrid tutorial](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/defining_grid_structures/) that talks you through defining grid structures including 'showHeader'.